# Nifi : How to move CSV content and its meta data to single table in Postgresdatabase using NiFi

Tags: postgresql, csv, apache-nifi, meta

I have csv files and I want to move the content of files along with its meta data (File name, source (To be hard coded), control number (Part of file name - to be extracted from file name itself) using NiFi. So here is the sample File name and layout -

**File name -** 12345_user_data.csv (control_number_user_data.csv)

**source -** Newyork

**CSV File Content/columns -**

**Fields -** abc1, abc2, abc3, abc4

**values -** 1,2,3,4

Postgres Database table layout

**Table name -** User_Education

**fields name  -**

control_number, file_name, source, abc1, abc2, abc3, abc4

**Values -**

12345, 12345_user_data.csv, Newyork, 1,2,3,4

I am planning to use below processors -

ListFile

FetchFile

UpdateAttributes

PutDatabaseRecords

LogAttributes

But I am not sure how to combine the actual content with the meta data to load into one single table. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UpdateRecord` before `PutDatabaseRecord` to add the `control_number`, `file_name`, and `source` fields to each record, setting the populating the "Replacement Value Strategy" property to "Literal Value" and use Expression Language to set the values to the corresponding attributes.

For example, you could have a user-defined property `/file_name` set to `${filename}`, that will add the `file_name` field to each record and set the value to whatever is in the "filename" attribute of the FlowFile.